# What is the difference between x.shape and tf.shape() in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, shapes

I wonder when I need to use tf.shape() and x.shape(). I'm currently using tensorflow 2.0 rc0

The following is an example code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.zeros((4, 3, 1)) 
print (tf.shape(a).numpy())
print (a.shape)
```

The result of the above code is as follows:

```
[4 3 1]
(4, 3, 1)
```

`tf.shape(a).numpy()` returns the numpy array whereas `a.shape` returns a tuple, but I cannot easily find which one is better and which one should be preferred.

Could anyone please give some advice on this?

Comment: NumPy arrays have smaller memory consumption and better runtime behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`.numpy()` on any `Tensor` or `Tensorflow ops` will return you `numpy.ndarray`.

**Example:**

```
a = tf.constant([1,2,3])
print(a.numpy())
print(tf.shape(a).numpy())
print(type(tf.shape(a)))
```

> [1 2 3]
>
> [3]
>
> `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>`

But `Tensor.shape()` will be having type `TensorShape` which will return a tuple.

```
print(type(a.shape))
```

> `<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.tensor_shape.TensorShape'>`

Even NumPy arrays have a shape attribute that returns a tuple of the length of each dimension of the array.

```
data = np.array([11, 22, 33, 44, 55])
print(data.shape)
```

> (5,)

The ideal way to use `tensor shape` in any of your operations would be `tf.shape(a)` without having to convert into `.numpy()` or use `Tensor.shape`

Hope this answers your question, Happy Learning!

Comment: 'The ideal way ...' Would you please elaborate on why is it ideal?

Answer (score 0):

I think one important difference is also that if you try to access the shape of tensor dimension which is not known in advance (e.g. None) using

```
tensor.shape
```

you will fail when building the graph of the network.

However, using

```
tf.shape(tensor)
```

will work as it will return the size in the execution. Might be useful for example if someone provides you batches of unknown sizes which can easily happen if you don't have data divisible by your batch_size and you need to work with the dimension of your batch.